# Titanium studio install modules

Tags: android, module, titanium

I have been trying this for a few days and still no hope.

I have downloaded this 
https://github.com/iamyellow/gcm.js

gcm.js by iamyellow, and install it in titanium through help->install mobile module-> select the .zip I downloaded.

After that I included it in my tiapp.xml in my project by it keeps showing requested module not found.

I even created a new project with this in my app.js and it still shows requested module not found

```
 require("net.iamyellow.gcmjs");
```

The folder is available in my ~/Library/Application support/Titanium/Modules/android , but I just cant import it into my app.

Answer (score 0):

According to the example provided in the distribution you should require the module like this:

```
var gcm = require('lib.gcm');
```